# How can i insert and get the data from db in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@posts = Post.all
```

Post.all returns all of the posts currently in the database as an array of Post records that we store in an instance variable called @posts. I want to get only specific data of the user.So how can i do it?

Comment: You really need to explain your question a bit more. Do you have a user model? Does this user model have a relationship with Post model? Show me the code!

Comment: Yes i have user model, but it does not have relationship with post model.

Comment: How can i establish the relationship between two models

Comment: Read Rails Guides at first (here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org), then everything (even asking proper questions ;-) ) should be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to generate a migration.

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer
```

Then, run `rake db:migrate`, so that your `posts` database table has a `user_id` column.

Now, you need to modify `user.rb` and `post.rb` model to reflect the association

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :posts
  ...
end
```

After this, restart your rails server. Now, you'll be able to access the posts specific to a user like this

```
# Let fetch User with ID 1
user = User.find(1)
# Now, we can fetch posts related to this user like
@posts = user.posts
# Or like this
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => 1).all
```

I hope that's easy to follow. Learn about [Rails ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

@posts = specific_user.posts.all

you need to make sure that the post model belongs_to the user model and that the user model has_many posts

Comment: How can i establish the relationship between two models

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is in the very first part of tutorials about Rails. Please do them first, otherwise you will be asking lots more questions and still not *understand* what you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the results, you can use the 'where' method.

For example, to filter Posts by username, try:

```
@posts = Posts.where(:username => "jondoe")
```

You can also use the :conditions symbol on the 'find' method, passing SQL in this case.

For example, to filter by username and public flag, try:

```
@posts = Posts.all(:conditions => "username='johndoe' AND public=1")
```